# Is there a difference between "Would you like some more" and "Would you like any more"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nuance

Consider the following sentences:

> 1. Would you like any more soup?
> 2. Would you like some more soup?

To my ears, they seem slightly different. If I'm a waiter and want to know whether to collect a client's soup bowl, I would ask the first. However, if I am simply going around the table offering soup with no plan to remove the bowl, I would use the second.

Am I imagining this or is there actually a slight difference in meaning between the two sentences? And, if so, how can we define it?

Comment: Since _any_ is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+%22Negative+Polarity+Item%22), and questions are negative environments, either one is OK in a question. Some people claim to detect some difference between the two, but rarely the same distinction. I.e, you you can use it to signal something if you want to, but others may use it to signal something completely different. YMMV.

Comment: @JohnLawler ah, so essentially, I *am* imagining it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is usually interpreted thus. The word *some* is normally used in neutral sentences, whereas *any* is often used in negative sentences. This becomes clear in the following examples:

> <s>She gave him any more soup.</s> [*any* not expected in a basic statement]
>
> *She **didn't** give him any more soup.* [*any* expected in a negative statement]
>
> *She gave him some more soup.* [*some* expected in a positive statement]
>
> *?She **didn't** give him some more soup.* [*some* not expected in a positive statement; this only works in special circumstances, like echo statements or contrastive focus:]
>
> *I hear she gave him some more soup. — Ah, but she **didn't** give him **some** more soup: she practically forced the entire pan down his throat!*

In a question, *any* is often connected with a negative expectation: an answer like "no" seems likely or at least very well possible to the asker.

So in this case you're indicating to your customers by *any* that you probably don't expect them to want more soup—or at least you expect this less than if you had used the neutral *some*. Since it is a waiter's job to seem welcoming and generous (with paid consumptions, but still), when he uses *some*, he indicates that he will not at all be surprised if you say "yes".

Simplified, this is taught in many schools as follows: a question with *some* expects "yes" or "no", while a question containing *any* expects "no".

Comment: In my mind, I could hear a mother asking her child _Would you like any more soup?_ just to prompt the child to refute the negative _no_ and answer with a more definite _yes_. But that's a remote scenario, so I'm upvoting both your answer and Lawler's [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358326/is-there-a-difference-between-would-you-like-some-more-and-would-you-like-any#comment832452_358326).

Comment: @Færd: Oh, absolutely: there are many layers to any linguistic utterance. There's locution, illocution, etc., and saying the opposite of what you mean, as in irony, is very common...

Comment: Yes, I think that would explain my perception. Is this expectation of a negative answer what John Lawler referred to [above](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358326/is-there-a-difference-between-would-you-like-some-more-and-would-you-like-any#comment832452_358326) as negative polarity?

Comment: I wholly agree. An expansive host/hostess would normally use *some* - *would you like some more?*. It would not sound terribly inviting if one was asked *would you like any more*. As has been rightly pointed out, it would appear to be inviting the answer *no*.

Comment: @ter: Yes, more or less. But I believe he also includes all questions in "negative polarity". To me, that kind of terminology is a bit confusing and counter-intuitive (for why is a standard question "negative"?); but what he really means is that English questions and negative sentences exhibit some similar syntactic patterns. For instance, the word *any* is common in both negative sentences and questions, but not in other types of sentences or clauses. Another example is *do*-support: *she likes me* [standard] → ***does** she like me?* [question]; *she **does**n't like me* [negation].

Comment: @terdon To paraphrase his comment: what he means by a "negative-polarity item" is an element of syntax that normally only occurs in questions and negative sentences; since *any* is such an element, it is OK to use *any* in a question. Then he touches upon the implications of using a negative-polarity item, like *any*, in a question, as compared to using a neutral element like *some* (I don't know his term for this: positive-polarity item?); he says that those implications are difficult to define and pinpoint, and that they may be perceived differently by different people.

Comment: It is my impression that he belongs to a very exact school of Anglo-Saxon linguistics, one which likes to define and plot language in exact ways—one which sees less value in those schools and methods of linguistics that resemble the natural sciences less.

Comment: I might add that, if we switch soup to iced tea, a waiter might ask "any more" once the meal is done, maybe the bill is paid, and the patron is lingering at the table, the expectation being that an answer of "no" means the patron is done and doesn't need any more service.  Whereas the waiter could ask "some more" at any point during the meal  and might ask again regardless of the answer.  In essence, "any more" has a slight implication that this is the patron's last chance to get some tea.

Answer (score 2):

Usually 'any' will be used in negative sentences like 'I don't have any soup' and 'some' is used in positive sentences like 'I have some soup'. When asking a question, we use the word 'any', for example 'Do you have any soup?' but when offering something, asking something, or suggesting something, the word 'some' is used instead of 'any'.